# Cant load a picture with java open cv

Tags: java, opencv

I tried putting all libraries in my project (it was describet like solution of this problem ) but there is still same problem.

```
Mat m = Highgui.imread("Koala.jpg");

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.highgui.Highgui.imread_1(Ljava/lang/String;)J
    at org.opencv.highgui.Highgui.imread_1(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.highgui.Highgui.imread(Highgui.java:352)
    at Open.main(Open.java:26)
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 22):

I got the same error and the below line worked for me.

System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

Answer (score 1):

Java can't currently see OpenCV, hence the linking error.

I'm on a Mac, so I link to its location on my drive:

```
System.load( "/opt/local/share/OpenCV/java/libopencv_java246.dylib" )
```

You might also be able to include the JAR directly in your lib folder in your project, but I've had success by pointing to the dylib.

Answer (score -1):

Set path as C:\opencv\build\java\x64 in your project properties. 
In Netbeans it is project-properties-run-vmoptions=-Djava.library.path="C:\opencv\build\java\x64"

In Eclipse, Add library Window-prreference-java-buildpath-userlibraries-new-opencv,,, Add external jars(add the opencv-300 jar)
set native library inside opencv as C:\opencv\build\java\x64. And add library to our project.

and to read an image use Imgcodecs.imread,
Mat img=Imgcodecs.imread("C:\Users\softroniics\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SceneRecogintion\src\com\SR\view\burj.png");

Comment: These instructions are very hard to read, I've tried editing it to add formatting to make it clearer, but I can't tell what you're trying to say. Please edit your answer to fix the typos and add some proper formatting (look at the hints to the right of your post when you edit to see the formatting options). You've also used file paths that are obviously specific to your own machine (like `C:\Users\softroniics`), which won't help anyone else.